# How to add to command line variable in gnu make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In gnu make I can add to a variable using the `+=` operator in a `Makefile`

```
V += foo
V += bar

all:
    echo "$(V)"
```

Running:

```
$ make
echo "foo bar"
foo bar
```

However if I define the variable on the command line,

```
$ make V=fail
echo "fail"
fail
```

then nothing is added.

how can I make gnu make add to the variable defined on the command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Command line assignments [take precedence over](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Override-Directive.html) in-makefile assignments, even if the in-makefile assignments are append operations.

To have the in-makefile assignments take precedence you have to use the `override` keyword:

```
override V += foo
override V += bar

all:
        echo "$(V)"
```

Comment: One could also use `V=fail make`, i.e. set it as an environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

For variable assignments in the makefile to override definitions on the command-line you need to use [`override` directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Override-Directive.html)

So the variable assignments in your makefile should look like:

```
override V += bar
```